# How can I move/replace this ABS p-trap?

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink

I installed a new vanity and sink, and found that the sink drain doesn’t line up with the p trap (also, incidentally, I’ll need a tailpiece extension - but that’s not my question).

I am trying to move the p trap but the swivel nut on the distal part of the p trap (pictured) is extremely stuck despite channellock pliers. Can I cut the abs just past the elbow and will there be a piece that fits over the cut end? Or should I cut all the way back at the PVC of the sanitary piece?[image]

Comment: heat often helps.  also try a pipe wrench, or footprints.

Answer (score 1):

It is all glued together, it will need to be cut of at a given spot and glue a wall adapter on the remainder of the cut off piece.

[image]
Picture courtesy Home Depot

If the white pipe (PVC) is at least 1" beyond the face of the wall, and glue is not smeared over it to any major degree, the pipe can be cut just behind the black (ABS) connector. Clean up the square cut you give it, get rid of any burrs, add PVC primer and glue to the wall adapter and pipe, and join together, holding it in place for a short while , until the glue grabs.

If there is not enough room to get the 1" needed to glue on the wall adapter with the original escutcheon on, when you cut the pipe and remove the escutcheon, this should get you another 3/8" of pipe exposed. Then use a "bell escutcheon" to cover the wall adapter once you connect the sink p-trap.

[image]
Picture courtesy Signature Hardware

This means the ABS p trap is useless and a new p trap will need to be installed. 
[image]

Wall adapters come in different sizes, make sure you get the right size, as well as the p trap.

Comment: Jack is right. Best to replace the entire assembly rather than piecemeal it.